# How to calculate percentage difference from first row to other rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have the data like the below:

```sql
create table Test(ID int,
A int)

insert into Test values
(1,   100),
(2,   200),
(3,   300),
(4,   400)
```

I want to calculate the percentage difference of the first row with other subsequent rows. For instance here % difference would be `0,100,200,300`. If the percentage difference is > 20% I could pick those rows. I could do it in Python but I was wondering whether there's some SQL version only?

I am using SQLite DB.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, postgres, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The `lag` window function will allow you to access a previous row's value. From there on, dividing a row and the previous row will give the ratio between them, and subtracting 1 (i.e., 100%) will give you the percentage change:

```sql
SELECT id, a
FROM   (SELECT id, a, LAG(a) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS lg
        FROM   mytable)
WHERE  lg IS NULL OR (a * 100.0 / lg) >= 120
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying `ID` value.? The % difference is for column A

Comment: @Volatil3 good catch, thanks! Indeed, it should be `a` in the `where` clause there. Just a stupid mistake on my side. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Diff percent should be 100 * (a - lg) / lg

Answer (score 0):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT ID, A
FROM (
  SELECT *, 1.0 * A / FIRST_VALUE(A) OVER (ORDER BY ID) - 1 diff
  FROM Test
)
WHERE diff > 0.2;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0ba8a14b4d5b400f21dde596f1375400).